# django south migration: Reset the schema only few tables

Tags: django, django-south

I am new django south migration. I have my main application and most of additional functions of that application I built as sub applications of the main application. Now what I want to do is reset the tables that are specific to sub application of the main application. I don't want to loose any data from other tables table.

This is how my database look like:

```
 public | tos_agreement                       | table | g_db_admin
 public | tos_agreementversion                | table | g_db_admin
 public | tos_signature                       | table | g_db_admin
 public | userclickstream_click               | table | g_db_admin
 public | userclickstream_stream              | table | g_db_admin
 public | vote                                | table | g_db_admin
(80 rows)
```

I only want to re-build (dump all data of)
 public | userclickstream_click               | table | g_db_admin
 public | userclickstream_stream              | table | g_db_admin

How can I do this using south migration.

In my south_migrationhistory table I have following:

```
  15 | userclickstream   | 0001_initial                                                                | 2013-12-10 13:26:15.684678-06
  16 | userclickstream   | 0002_auto__del_field_stream_auth_user                                       | 2013-12-10 13:26:15.693485-06
  17 | userclickstream   | 0003_auto__del_field_stream_username__add_field_stream_user                 | 2013-12-10 13:26:15.721449-06
```

I assume this record took place when I initially wired up it with south migration.

I was also thinking what if? 
Delete the above records from south_migrationhistory and re-run the migration for this app which will generate the tables.

```
./manage.py schemamigration userclickstream --initial
./manage.py migrate userclickstream
```

Comment: write your own migration?

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

1. Open up your terminal and write `manage.py dumpdata > backup.json`. it will create a json fixture with all data currently in the database. That way, if you screw up anything, you can always re-load the data with `manage.py loaddata backup.json` (note that all tables need to be empty for this to work).
2. **optional**: pass the data to a new development db using the aformentioned `loaddata` command
3. Write your own migration, and not worry about breaking anything because - hey, you got a backup. It might take some learning, but the basic idea is you create a migration class with two functions - forward and reverse. Check out the [south documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and pick it up slowly from there.
4. Come back to SO with any more specific question and troubles you have along the way

This isn't a coded "here's the solution" answer, but I hope this helps nonetheless

Comment: what if I do re-initialization or drop those two tables delete the records in south migration, because I feel there is easier way that creating a script such a simple job.

Comment: come again? I don't think I understand what you're asking

Comment: I have edited the question and I am hoping someone else has a better answer.

Comment: If all you need is to drop a few tables, you can always do that through your SQL. re-initializing isn't such a good idea because you might run into weird errors with other parts of the application that you want to stay the same

Comment: I need to re-create these tables again. Also this app is sub app of main application.

Comment: You can delete the data without dropping the tables. SQL: `DELETE * FROM table_name;` or django orm: `Mymodel.objects.all().delete()`

Comment: Thanks but if these tables have dependency then it will not let me delete right?

Comment: It will simply delete the related dependencies too

Comment: Just try it. Create a backup like I showed you and manually delete the data. If anything bad happens just reload the backup